# OpenFeint 2.12.5 - offline config doesnt work

Tags: iphone, openfeint

I am using Xcode 4 and OpenFeint 2.12.5, on iPhone 4.2 and iPad 4.3
I've downloaded openfeint_offline_config.xml from the dev site and added it to the project, but I still get the message:
"No offline support / No offline functionality has been enabled for (null)"

This message appears after I select USE OPENFEINT and then choose user to log in - pop up box appears and reappears when I click OK (basically cannot be closed)

I tried cleaning, rebuilding and adding offline_config to various places in the project structure

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after trying several things (clean/build, re-download offline config xml, etc.) finally found the solution.

The problem lies in the app version associated with the leaderboards and achievements. You need to make sure that you've set your app's bundle version in your info.plist (in Xcode) to your latest version and that it is in between the leaderboards "min" and "max" configuration on your openfeint dashboard.

In my case, my old app version was 1.01. I was creating a new app, version 1.02, and configured that version in openfeint. I then set the leaderboards to start from my new version 0001.02.00 through to 9999.99.99, except I forgot to update my bundle version to 1.02 in my plist. That's when the problem showed up.

Updating my plist bundle version solved it.

Hope that helps!